# interpolation error - image request before resource link is populated

Tags: angularjs, interpolation

I am building an angular app. The REST call works and populates all necessary data, but it appears to be firing off a request before the variables are injected. Here is the error I'm getting:

> GET http://localhost:10001/%7B%7Bproduct.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

This error fires before the interpolation of the page, and then everything loads correctly. The link it is pointing to is a src link for an img. The end of this URL should be replaced with a link to an image resource, but the variable has not been populated by interpolation yet.

What else can I tell you so that I can track this issue down?

**Markup**

```
<div class="headerWrap box-shadow">
    <h2 class="box-shadow">Product Selection</h2>
</div>
<ul class="products">
    <li ng-repeat="product in products" class="productPane box-shadow">
        <a ng-href="#/products/{{product.product_id}}" target="newtab">
            <div class="productMeta box-shadow">
                <img ng-src="{{product.image}}">
                <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{(product.price/100) | currency: "&euro;" : 2}}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try using [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: Ok, I added the ng- to the attr, and now it's only populating half the images. It actually made it worse. :( Your suggestion does seem like the right first step, but now I get no error and only have the pics.

Comment: If I look at what is rendered in the DOM, it has the correct link in the element with the missing image. I can paste the link into a browser and visit it, but it's not appearing.

Comment: If I understand, you have an anchor tag that has a `href` to an image that needs to be interpolated? If so, try `<a ng-href="whatever/{{ yourUri }}">`

Comment: I added ng- to the href as well. The problem is with the <img> element, however.

Comment: what is `product.image` ? Is this s fully qualified uri?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here is an example of one: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/images/1.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75657/discussion-between-sal-niro-and-kraken).